# SMTP failed to connect through phpmailer. Given the code below

Tags: php, email

```
    <?php
if(!empty($_POST["forgot-password"])){
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345", "omar_wacoa");
$condition = "";
if(!empty($_POST["user-login-name"])) 
$condition = " ku_id = '" . $_POST["user-login-name"] . "'";
if(!empty($_POST["user-email"])) {
if(!empty($condition)) {
$condition = " and ";
}
$condition = " email = '" . $_POST["user-email"] . "'";
}
if(!empty($condition)) {
$condition = " where " . $condition;
}
$sql = "Select * from user " . $condition;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(!empty($user)) {
echo "hello";
require_once("forgot-password-recovery-mail.php");
} else {
$error_message = 'No User Found';
}
    }
?>
<link href="demo-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
function validate_forgot() {
    if((document.getElementById("user-login-name").value == "") && (document.getElementById("user-email").value == "")) {
        document.getElementById("validation-message").innerHTML = "Login name or Email is required!"
        return false;
    }
    return true
}
</script>
<form name="frmForgot" id="frmForgot" method="post" onSubmit="return validate_forgot();">
<h1>Forgot Password?</h1>
<?php if(!empty($success_message)) { ?>
<div class="success_message"><?php echo $success_message; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="validation-message">
<?php if(!empty($error_message)) { ?>
<?php echo $error_message; ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="field-group">
<div><label for="username">Username</label></div>
<div><input type="text" name="user-login-name" id="user-login-name" class="input-field"> Or</div>
</div>  
<div class="field-group">
<div><label for="email">Email</label></div>
<div><input type="text" name="user-email" id="user-email" class="input-field"></div>
</div>
<div class="field-group">
<div><input type="submit" name="forgot-password" id="forgot-password" value="Submit" class="form-submit-button"></div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

mailconfiguration.php

```
<?php
define("PROJECT_HOME","http://localhost/wacoa_f");
define("PORT","587"); // port number
define("MAIL_USERNAME", "user@gmail.com"); // smtp usernmae
define("MAIL_PASSWORD", "ffdg"); // smtp password
define("MAIL_HOST", "smtp.gmail.com"); // smtp host
define("MAILER", "smtp");
define("SENDER_NAME", "Admin");
define("SERDER_EMAIL", "admin@admin.com");
?>
```

forgot-password-recovery-mail.php

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//require( 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' );
require_once("mail_configuration.php");
$body = "<div>" . $user["ku_id"] . ",<br><br><p>Click this link to recover your password<br><a href='" . PROJECT_HOME . "php-forgot-password-recover-code/reset_password.php?name=" . $user["ku_id"] . "'>" . PROJECT_HOME . "php-forgot-password-recover-code/reset_password.php?name=" . $user["ku_id"] . "</a><br><br></p>Regards,<br> Admin.</div>";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port     = PORT;  
$mail->Username = MAIL_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = MAIL_PASSWORD;
$mail->Host     = MAIL_HOST;
$mail->Mailer   = MAILER;
//sender
$mail->SetFrom(SERDER_EMAIL, SENDER_NAME);
$mail->ReturnPath=SERDER_EMAIL; 
//recepient
$mail->AddAddress($user["email"]);
$mail->Subject = "Forgot Password Recovery";        
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    $error_message = 'Problem in Sending Password Recovery Email';
} else {
    $success_message = 'Please check your email to reset password!';
}

?>
```

Here I am trying to submit a form with the recover email which send a link to reset the password for the user.I have user PHPMailer .But it gives me the error as :

> 2017-11-21 06:48:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   2017-11-21 06:48:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>   2017-11-21 06:48:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>   2017-11-21 06:48:04
>   SMTP connect() failed.   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: You should indent your code properly. That would help both us an you to follow the flow and debug the code. Right now, it's pretty hard to read. One thing I _do_ see is that **you're wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use **[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Try with  `$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";` and PORT = 465

Comment: **ALERT** Delete your question immediately, change your username and password to dummy  in code then repost your question. Don't share username and password to any one

Comment: Its not working.I have tried it

Answer (score 0):

on mail configuration.php it is supposed to be define ("SENDER_EMAIL","admin@admin.com"); not

define("SERDER_EMAIL", "admin@admin.com"); & on forgot-password-recovery-mail.php

under //sender those two lines supposed to be SENDER as well not SERDER
its syntax error otherwise it should be working since ive tested it yesterday